# Simple way to detect variable presence and display html conditionally with angular

Tags: view, angularjs, conditional-statements

I am using Angular for the first time, and I have a collection of $scope.products.

Say I have this:

`{{product.image_one}}` which is not set yet, because a user has not uploaded an image. I would like to conditionally display an upload button using Angular.

What is the simples possible way to detect if product.image_one is undefined, and to display conditionally some dom using angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ngShow` directive:

```
<div class="upload-button" ng-show="product.image_one">
....
</div>
```